# Store array of objects or create when needed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, memory-management

I'm new to objective-c and ios, but I'm coming along alright.  Now I've run into a situation where I can see two ways of arriving at the same destination.  I'm just curious as to which way would better suit the efficiency of the program.  I apologize in advance if there are better ways of phrasing all this that I don't know of yet.

(removing all prior context)..The meat of the matter is this:

My first object is a rectangular UIView object that may have rotational transformation applied.  This object has properties that stores the CGPoints of the location of the four transformed corners.

```
rectangularView.h
<...>

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint topLeft;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint topRight;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint bottomLeft;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint bottomRight;
```

I have created a Line object:

```
line.h
<...>

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint pointA;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint pointB;
@property (nonatomic) float m;   // slope
@property (nonatomic) float b;   // y-intercept
```

Basically, the Line objects represent the sides of the rectangularView.  These lines will get stored in an array.

Elsewhere there is a method that is able to determine whether two Line objects intersect in order to determine whether one rectangularView intersects with another.

```
- (BOOL)checkLineIntersection:lineA:lineB
```

QUESTION:
  When checkLineIntersection:lineA:lineB is called it needs to obviously send two Line objects.  Would it be better for:

- (A) The line objects to be created and stored within each of the rectangularView objects?

  - Pros:  The line's would already be created and just need to be passed to the method, yielding faster processing
  - Cons:  More memory would be utilized
- (B) Create the line objects just before sending them to the method.

  - Pros:  The Line objects would not be taking up memory
  - Cons:  More processing time during all the loops of creating the sides for all the rectangularView objects before sending them to the method

Basically, if there is a comparison rectangularView (compView)

```
[OPTION A]

for (RectangularView *rv in rectangularViewArray) {
    BOOL doesIntersect = [self checkLineIntersection:[rv lineA] lineB:[compView lineA]];
    <...>
```

or

```
[OPTION B]

for (RectangularView *rv in rectangularViewArray) {
    Line *lineA = [[Line alloc].....
    Line *lineB = [[Line alloc]....
    <...>
    BOOL doesIntersect = [self checkLineIntersection:[rv lineA] lineB:[compView lineA]];
```

I'm leaning towards Option A in order to split up processing time between events, meaning the lines get designed and calculated when the rectangularView is created, and they only need to be recalled when they are sent for intersection testing.

Thank you..and I hope I wrote this out well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn to use instruments. They are a very good tool suite, you can look at all sorts of metrics, leaks, heap space, performance numbers.  I am of the mind that you should run some profiling in your application and decide from their based on what you see. It's hard to give a definitive a or b answer here.

Comment: Good point.  I guess now is as good of a time as any to start learning about the instruments.  I'd vote this up, but my rep isn't high enough yet.  But, thanks.

Comment: Learning instruments really is an investment worth making. There are excellent videos iniTunes from apple's WWDC that can guide you. Also you should be able to select my response as the answer rather than upvoting  if you see fit.